# Change Parse Application when App is running

Tags: parse-platform

I have an Android Application that works with locals instalations and I want use it with diferents Parse applications. Each instalation administrator will contract with Parse directly. When app start it will look for the keys for parse.

I wonder how to change the Parse App linkeded in the Android App once this is running

I have tried to call Parse.initialize (context, apllicationId, clientKey) twice but it doesn't work. I have tried the app register in diferent Parse App every time you start the App link with a different Parse App

It´s always linked only with the first application

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle){

    super.onCreate(icicle);
    final  Context context = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.ssa);
    getActionBar().hide();

    // Getting the global variables
    fmGlobalsBean = Utilities.getGlobals(this);

    if(!"".equals(fmGlobalsBean.getUrl_server())){

     Parse.initialize(contexto, "p4IWkTRc0WTdKkMH6r60hjYzwX1TIXChy8VcDvPb",  "KhkcX4G3dqVpRawHyIYfnHAWqj1H2vyhwD3wINlQ");
     ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
     ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(fmGlobalsBean.getUrl_server());           
    }      
    else
    {
    Parse.initialize(this, "Y3xgZ58u4Qcn9TrovFqCOe4PBzhURjXooZ3vDKgB", "ealo3nm4wa4lbJ7KrSR2OSf60DZiUjEUjdUJTQzs");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("INITIAL");
    }
}
```